# Power of summation of two signals

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, continuous-signals

Let $|A|$ denote the power of the analog signal $A$. Is that true to assume $|A+B|=|A|+|B|$, for two arbitrary signals $|A|$ and $|B|$? That is the power of the summation of two signals is -at least roughly- equal to the summation of the powers of the two signals. What if $A$ and $B$ are random signals?

Comment: Try it with $B = A$ and $B = -A$ to see if your proposed bound makes any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the amplitude, the inequation $|a+b|≤|a|+|b|$ is satisfied.

However, since the power includes a square calculation on the amplitude, you can find all the three ($=$,$\leq$,and $\geq$) relations.

The difference is that amplitude is a vector, while power is a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not true. It is

\begin{equation}
|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|
\end{equation}

Edit: This is not true for the power which was asked for by the OP (see the comments). I over-read the re-definition of $|\cdot|$.

Comment: As an additional counterexample to the OP's question, let $B = -A$ and see what the power of $A + B$ looks like.

Comment: The displayed equation in this answer is incorrect.  If $B = A$ instead of $-A$ as in @JasonR's comment, then it certainly is not true that $|A+B| \leq |A|+|B|$ since $|A+B| = |2A| = 4|A| > |A|+|A| = 2|A|$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: How do you come from $|2A|$ to $4|A|$. Maybe we are talking about a different meaning of $|\cdot|$ here. I mean the absolute value and for this, the shown equation is certainly true.

Comment: What you say is true about the amplitude. But the OP decided to use $|\cdot|$ for power instead of amplitude, and I am just following his notation. See also the answer by @lennon310. The (instantaneous) _power_ (into a $1$-$\Omega$ resistor) of the signal $2x(t)$ is $(2x(t))^2 = 4x^2(t)$ which is $4$ times the (instantaneous) power of the signal $x(t)$.  This carries over into _average_ power as well since the average power of $s(t)$ over $T$ seconds is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T (s(t))^2\,\mathrm dt$.